# Default location for new career items is inconsistent with item truncation

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

When you add a new experience item, education item, answer, etc., to your careers profile, it gets added at the end. Assuming profiles are progressively updated over time, this implies that the intent is to list in chronological order (or play whack-a-mole with the reorder arrows).

In employer view, lists of sufficient length are truncated. Presumably, the most important information is displayed, with more detail available by clicking "display *x* more...". Generally, the most recent items are the most important for employers to see. This implies the intent is to list in reverse chronological order.

Comment: **play whack-a-mole with the reorder arrows** this observation deserves its own +1 alone. Adding items at top also makes good sense to me, but I can't +1 twice :)

Answer (score 1):

This suggests you write you resume from the bottom up.  Most people write their resumes from the top down because it's easier to remember the most recent things you've done.

Comment: There are two phases of profile composition: initial creation and maintenance. Agreed, for initial creation, a newest to oldest workflow is most intuitive. For maintenance, however, without a flux capacitor, oldest to newest is the only option. The UI should support both user stories.